# Ksoap2 : Calling DateTime datatype on .NET Web Service

Tags: c#, java, wcf, datetime, ksoap2

I have a WCF Web Service. This service I have tested successfully on .NET Platform.

I use Ksoap 2 to generate Java classes file to consume this service. When use KSoap2, `DateTime` Datatype becomes String (Due to Java doesn't have DateTime datatype comparable with DateTime in .NET)

So, at getter attribute for object, I don't know how to set value :

for example :

```
student.birth = "12/12/2013"
student.birth = "2013/12/12"
```

I have tested on some case, but maybe because the format is not true, I get this exception :

```
This Value cannot be set to NULL
```

I don't know which value. But I guess birth field above.

So. My question is : How to use DateTime data type in KSoap ? Which structure should I put in datetime string ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My only guess would be to use datetime.format strings

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
public class DateExample
{
    private DateTime _dt;
    public string dt
    {
        get
        {
            return _dt.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt",
                System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            // Displays 06:09:01 PM 
        }
        private set { }
    }
}
```

Comment: I program on Java. not C#. The problem I have met is because in Java, I don't know how to format like on .NET Do you have any other ideas for my problem ? Thanks :)

Comment: I was referring to returning a formatted date from your Web service